# SessionStorage is not cleared?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

My understanding of `sessionStorage` is that it should be cleared when the session ends (browser/tab is closed, user navigates away, that kinda thing). Which is the desired behaviour.

However, in Chrome (the target browser) it isnt cleared on any of these events but seems to persist a la `localStorage`.

Any ideas why? I am wondering if its some weird setting in chrome where I sync from desktop to laptop or something?

Other than cookies, any way to solve this for a specific domain/application?

In case it changes anything

- `sessionStorage` is accessed through a `WebStorage`
- We are using ReactJS
- latest version of Chrome available for Mac M1

Comment: Is it possible to recreate this behaviour standalone in a codepen or similar?

Comment: No, it works as expected in codepen - and I can't share the code for security reasons either :(

Comment: Was wondering if this was an issue anyone else has come across?